# how to parse a two doubles from editText?

Tags: android, string-parsing

I develop a simple calculator, and I have a problem. When I input the values ​​for the calculations, the first digit is parsed only.For example, if you enter 5 + 3, then the result will be 5.How to solve this problem? Thank's for any answers.

My code:

```
String[] val = mInputVal.getText().toString().split("\\+");
    try{
        inputNum1 =  Double.parseDouble(val[0]);
        inputNum2 =  Double.parseDouble(strVal);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For second index just do this : `inputNum2 =  Double.parseDouble(val[1]);` Or make sure strVal = val[1]. And make sure that the string gets split properly. What is happening is that , there is just 1 string in val , due to which val[1] gives you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. Hope that helps.

Comment: how can I fix this problem?

Comment: The issue is , your string is not getting split properly.

Answer (score 2):

`inputNum2 = Double.parseDouble(val[1]);` ?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: this is correct answer, the exception means you're trying to access element [n] in array with less than n elements.

example (pseudocode) ourArray = array(3, 5, 7, 11) you try to access element like ourArray[6] or ourArray[4] this gives this error since there are only elements with four indexes starting from 0: 0, 1, 2, 3. only using them in ourArray[...] is correct, others will give you error like it did.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that parser parses string untill first non-number, whitch you have " 3". So you should call

```
inputNum2 =  Double.parseDouble(val[1].trim());
```